# How to access to caller details with Avaya?

Tags: avaya

Our support team uses Avaya phones, they use in-house CRM. One of the requirements from them is to get access to caller id so that CRM application can display caller specific details. Does Avaya provides any API to achieve the same?

Comment: Yes, it's called TSAPI.

Answer (score 1):

That depends of what equipment they have.

1. If the Agents user One-x Agent you already have screenpop. You can launch a custom URL with the data that One-X have (ANI -callerID-, VDN, DNIS, UUI, etc).
2. If they have physical phones (desktop phones) you will need to go in other way like a custom development but in this case you will need to have licenses and other servers like AES (*Application Enablement Services*) and advanced Tsapi development knowledge about how to do it.

Do a little research over the Avaya support site about *AES SDK Tsapi*, and *DMCC SDK*.